# Using JUnit @ResourceLock to execute some test classes sequentially

Tags: java, junit5

I've got a large integration tests suite, test classes are executed in parallel and class methods are executed sequentially. There are 2 test classes which use the same service for creating/reading/removing entities, and sharing this service creates a race condition:

1. Class Foo is creating a record
2. Class Bar is removing all records
3. Class Foo is trying to read the created record asserting that it exists, but at this point it's been removed by Bar.

I tried annotating both classes with JUnit's `@ResourceLock` but it didn't work, maybe I'm missing something?

Example:

```
@ResourceLock("serivceResource")
class Foo {
@Test
void fooTest(){
//create a record
//read the created record
//assert record created
}
}



@ResourceLock("serivceResource")
class Bar {
@Test
void barTest(){
//wipe all records
}
}
```

`Foo#fooTest` and `Bar#barTest` are in race condition dispute the use of `@ResourceLock`.

I wonder maybe I need to configure JUnit somehow for it to work?

Comment: How you use @ResourceLock? Any code?

Comment: @QingfeiYuan I just annotated the two classes with it passing the same string as the resource key param to the annotation

Comment: I think the ResourceLock annotation uses an `Object`... not the value of a String. "serviceResource" and "serviceResource" are 2 different Objects so the ResourceLocks will not block eachother. You need to create static String and reference it for each lock

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce and found tests below work as expected with and without resource lock

```
@ResourceLock("serivceResource")
class Foo {
    @BeforeAll static void beforeAll() { call("Foo.beforeAll");}
    @BeforeEach void beforeEach() { call("Foo.beforeEach");}
    @AfterAll static void afterAll() { call("Foo.afterAll");}
    @AfterEach void afterEach() { call("Foo.afterEach");}
    @Test void test1(){ call("Foo.test1");}
    @Test void test2(){ call("Foo.test2");}
    @Test void test3(){ call("Foo.test3");}

    private static void call(String action) {
        System.out.println("Enter "+action);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Leave "+action);
    }
}

@ResourceLock("serivceResource")
class Bar {

    @BeforeAll static void beforeAll() { call("Bar.beforeAll");}
    @BeforeEach void beforeEach() { call("Bar.beforeEach");}
    @AfterAll static void afterAll() { call("Bar.afterAll");}
    @AfterEach void afterEach() { call("Bar.afterEach");}
    @Test void test1(){ call("Bar.test1");}
    @Test void test2(){ call("Bar.test2");}
    @Test void test3(){ call("Bar.test3");}

    private static void call(String action) {
        System.out.println("Enter "+action);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Leave "+action);
    }
}
```

Output if resource lock is set - everything is serialized

```
Enter Bar.beforeAll
Leave Bar.beforeAll
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.test1
Leave Bar.test1
Enter Bar.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.test2
Leave Bar.test2
Enter Bar.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.test3    
Leave Bar.test3
Enter Bar.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Enter Bar.afterAll
Leave Bar.afterAll
Enter Foo.beforeAll
Leave Foo.beforeAll
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Enter Foo.test1
Leave Foo.test1
Enter Foo.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Enter Foo.test2
Leave Foo.test2
Enter Foo.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Enter Foo.test3
Leave Foo.test3
Enter Foo.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Enter Foo.afterAll
Leave Foo.afterAll
```

Output if resource lock is not set - everything is parallel. (Though, beforeAll/afterAll look very, very strange!)

```
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.beforeEach
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Enter Foo.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Leave Foo.beforeEach
Leave Bar.beforeEach
Enter Bar.test3
Enter Foo.test1
Enter Bar.test1
Enter Foo.test3
Enter Foo.test2
Enter Bar.test2
Leave Bar.test3
Leave Bar.test1
Leave Foo.test3
Leave Foo.test1
Leave Foo.test2
Leave Bar.test2
Enter Bar.afterEach
Enter Bar.afterEach
Enter Foo.afterEach
Enter Foo.afterEach
Enter Bar.afterEach
Enter Foo.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Leave Foo.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Leave Bar.afterEach
Enter Foo.beforeAll
Enter Bar.beforeAll
Leave Foo.beforeAll
Leave Bar.beforeAll
Enter Bar.afterAll
Enter Foo.afterAll
Leave Bar.afterAll
Leave Foo.afterAll
```

**My guess - your `Foo` test interferes with some other test not `Bar`**

Comment: `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;`

`import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.ResourceLock;`

Comment: Hi. I tried to reproduce and could not, see updated answer. My guess - your Foo test interferes with some other test not Bar

Comment: Also note, you made typo here `@ResourceLock("serivceResource")` (serivce vs service) so probably it causes problem if some other test (not Foo nor Bar) refers lock without typo.